# JSON Return with Params Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, repository-pattern

I Want to Get all The state Using the reference key of country in the state table to json result so i can cascade in a dropdownlist of ASP.NET MVC and Having this Error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'countryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult StateList(Int32)' in '_5._1_Presentation.MVC.Areas.Registration.Controllers.RegistrationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

this is my Service, Controller Repo Query

Controller

```
public JsonResult StateList(int countryId)
    {
        var state = _countryState.GetAllState(countryId);

        return Json(new SelectList(state, "CountryId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Service

```
public IEnumerable<State> GetAllState(int countryId)
    {
        var GetallState = UnitOfWork.State.GetAllStateByCountry(countryId);

        return GetallState.ToList();
    }
```

Repo Query

```
public class StateRepository : BaseRepository<State>, IStateRepository
{
    public StateRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<State> GetAllStateByCountry(int Id)
    {
        DbSet.Where(dto => dto.CountryId == Id)
            .Include(dto => dto.Country);
        return DbSet;
    }
}
```

This is all I get but I cant Really Figure out were the Issue is coming...
Will Really Appreciate your help...

this is the Controller calling the country to the dropdown

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var queryCountry = _countryState.GetAllCountry();
        ViewBag.CountryName = new SelectList(queryCountry, "CountryId", "CountryName"));

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling the `StateList` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in how you are calling the action method. You aren't passing a `countryId` but as it is not a nullable type an exception is thrown.

You can either:

Change the `countryId` to be an `int?` (but you'll need to handle `null`'s in `StateList` as `GetAllState` doesn't take an `int?`)

or

You can check how you are calling the action and ensure you are passing the `countryId`.

**Edit**

In your comment on @Exception's answer you mention you are calling the URL like this:

> localhost:28636/Registration/Registration/StateList/1

If you are using the default routing you will have a route defined like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This is going to try to map the `1` you have sent to a parameter called `id` **but** your parameter is called `countryId` so no value is mapped to `countryId`. As `countryId` is not nullable an exception is raised.

Renaming your parameter to to `id` like this:

```
public JsonResult StateList(int? id)
{
    var state = _countryState.GetAllState(id);

    return Json(new SelectList(state, "CountryId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

will fix your issue or alternatively you can call the URL with the explicit parameter name like this

> localhost:28636/Registration/Registration/StateList?countryId=1

**Edit 2**

After the comment:

> Yes it Okay but there is a problem, It retrive evry state from database intead of getting the state where Country Id is =1

I think this is because you are filtering the results but not returning them. Instead you are returning `DbSet`. Your `GetAllStateByCountry` should be more like this:

```
public IQueryable<State> GetAllStateByCountry(int Id)
{
    return DbSet.Where(dto => dto.CountryId == Id)
        .Include(dto => dto.Country);
}
```

Comment: Yes it Okay but there is a problem, It retrive evry state from database intead of getting the state where Country Id is =1

Comment: WOW... That's it Thank you very mush just save my day cuz I was wondering why it didn't do the trick thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make `countryId nullable` as :

```
public JsonResult StateList(int? countryId)  
{
    if(countryId != null){
     var state = _countryState.GetAllState(countryId);
     return Json(new SelectList(state, "CountryId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else{
     return Json(new{ }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just did and now showing error in this line  var state = _countryState.GetAllState(countryId);..... that i cant use int? to int

Comment: when you are calling StateList from your view just make sure that you are posting something in countryId...

Comment: Yea It Ok but it not suppose to return null because am trying to choose country and populate the next drop down with the state reference to that country Id.... I DONT WANT TO RETURN NULL PLEASE

Comment: then make sure that you are passing something in countryId from your view..@user3811481

Comment: I am...

when i query this, http://localhost:28636/Registration/Registration/StateList/1,

this is my Error

This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.


But I ALLOW JSON GET in my controller

Comment: @user3811481...instead of querying this way just do it that way.... localhost:28636/Registration/Registration/StateList?countryId=1...

Comment: query like this brings all state from database with reference country of 2,3,4... will that work with my Ajax get for the drop down?

Comment: It Work Well Thanks for you help I Had to change my service to

var GetallState = UnitOfWork.State.GetAll().Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId);

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller code to this:

```
public JsonResult StateList(int? countryId)
    {
      if (countryId != null && countryId.HasValue)
      {
          var state = _countryState.GetAllState(countryId.Value);
          return Json(new SelectList(state, "CountryId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }

      return Json(null);    

    }
```

By doing this - you will allow nulls for countryID and you will return an empty json in case they pass you a null value for countryID.

Comment: Yea It Ok but it not suppose to return null because am trying to choose country and populate the next drop down with the state reference to that country Id.... I DONT WANT TO RETURN NULL PLEASE

Comment: @user3811481 what do you want to return if the country is invalid ?

Comment: Null... But the fact is that all country in the database has states in the state table

Comment: @user3811481 yes but the problem is that you are calling the method with the null so the problem must be in the method that generates the first dropdown or in the ajax request you are making. The problem is that this method recieves null for countryID.

Comment: Yes I think Thats the Problem Am Editting my question for you to see the get country controller